# PHP Make an excerpt by cutting the string on the last space after x characters

Tags: php

I'm trying to make excerpts from long texts while deleting everything that comes after the last space if the string length is more than 110 characters.

```
        $string = 'Стихи похожи на людей: помнят прошлое и ничего не знают о будущем, хотят жить вечно, a страница уже перелистывается.';

        if (mb_strlen($string ) > 110) {
            $pos = mb_strpos($string , ' ', 110);
            $excerpt = rtrim(mb_substr($string, 0, $pos), '.,—-_!@\'"()*#~').'...';
        }
```

If I print with `print_r(mb_strlen($pos));` the result of `$pos` is `0`, and its working correctly if I change `$pos` to `$pos = mb_strpos($quote_content, ' ', 99);`.

The last word in this case is 16 characters long and the whole string is 116 characters long so it makes perfect sense as to why a 99 offset works while anything above will result a `$pos` value of `0` thus instead of making an excerpt it just returns `...` (based on the current example).

I have quite a few strings here with different string length and words length so I need a dynamic solution that will work in all cases. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, It's early. Have you tried to loop counting backwards to see if it will shorten the string to the desired length? So since 100 returns 0 then loop back to 99. etc etc

Comment: There is a pretty good example in [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) See the sample code from `ju1ius` from 6 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple (and fast) way to cut a string to a fixed number of characters is with `preg_replace`:

```
$string = 'Стихи похожи на людей: помнят прошлое и ничего не знают о будущем, хотят жить вечно, a страница уже перелистывается.';
$excerpt = preg_replace('/^(.{1,110})\s.*$/u', '$1...', $string);
echo $excerpt;
```

Output:

```
Стихи похожи на людей: помнят прошлое и ничего не знают о будущем, хотят жить вечно, a страница уже...
```

The regex works by looking for some number of characters `^(.{1,110})\s` (from 1 to 110) from the start of a string and up to a space character. Since the quantifier is greedy it takes as many characters as it can. Those characters are captured in a group. The rest of the string is then matched by `.*$`, and the whole string is replaced by the first capture group and three `.'s` (`$1...`), giving just the first portion as desired. The `u` flag on the regex means it will count unicode characters correctly. To adjust the length of the excerpt, simply change the `110` to whatever length you need.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcA7gd/9)

**Edit**

The regex can also be modified to strip off any non-word characters (so you don't end up with `the quick brown fox,...`) by modifying it to insist that the last character of the capture group is a `word` character and then allowing the following character to be a non-word character:

```
$string = 'Стихи похожи на людей: помнят прошлое и ничего не знают о будущем, хотят жить вечно, a страница уже перелистывается.';
$excerpt = preg_replace('/^(.{1,23}\w)\W.*$/u', '$1...', $string);
echo $excerpt;
```

Output:

```
Стихи похожи на людей...
```

[Updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcA7gd/10)

Comment: This is amazing. I didn't know you can do that with regex. Is there a way to remove any special characters and/or commas/periods from the end before we add three `.'s`? Otherwise, if there's a comma at the end it will become `a страница уже,...`.

Comment: @Ricardo FYI I benchtested 100k iterations of the accepted answer and my edited (which is more flexible) and the times were 0.315 for the accepted answer and 0.192 for this answer.

Comment: A lot of new information in this answer, no other choice than marking it as the (better) answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This will cut the string at the last space without cutting words:

```
$excerpt = mb_substr($string, 0, mb_strrpos($string, ' ', -(mb_strlen($string) - 110)));
```

`strrpos` and `mb_strrpos` go backwards so you can search the last occurrence starting from the given position

Comment: This works, thanks :) Now I'm trying to decide whether `mb_substr` is better than regex (Nick's answer) in terms of performance, any insight on that?

Comment: I don't know about performance... as for my personal taste I usually prefer using regular functions if they exist, especially if you have to deal with other programmers not so fond on regular expressions.

Of course this applies to yourself too: if you're not that fond wit regex you may have problems maintaining that code you didn't write ;-)

This article may help about performances: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342427/are-preg-match-and-preg-replace-slow)

Answer (score 0):

A lazy fix by checking all chars from 110 until space was found

```
    // lazy fix by checking all chars from 110 until space was found

    if (mb_strlen($string) > 110) {
        $p = 110;
        while(!($pos = mb_strpos($string , ' ', $p--))){};
        $excerpt = rtrim(mb_substr($string, 0, $pos), '.,—-_!@\'"()*#~') . ' ... ';
    }
```