# How to limit words in a echo field

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have this code, I need to limit the word in the field "newsContenuto" and add some"..." .

```
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$newsID}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$newsData}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$newsAutore}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$newsTitolo}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$newsContenuto}</td>";
        echo "<td>";
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php can help

Comment: If you want to make sure you only break on a space character (so don't have something like `hel...`), this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114612/php-make-an-excerpt-by-cutting-the-string-on-the-last-space-after-x-characters/52115331#52115331

Answer (score 3):

Try this example:

```
echo "<td>" . substr( $newsContenuto, 0, 20 ) . "...</td>";
```

In the above code, I've set 20, you can increase that.

Comment: Thanks for quickly answer, but this is the output:

Comment: Sorry, I've extra quotation at end of the string, I've fixed above code.

Comment: Oh, wait...there's a more " that I remove, now it work great! Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome, please check as answered if it helped you :)